# Doing the one mode projection using sql query

Tags: sql, social-networking, projection, bipartite

Assume that we have a table that contains:

```
UserID, ProjectID
```

This table has another representation in network analysis called [bipartite graph.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)

Can we make an efficient [one mode projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) using SQL query?

Example of one mode projection:
Assume that the table is:

```
UserId, ProjectID
U1, P1
U2, P1
U3, P1
U4, P2
U5, P2
U1, P2
```

The one mode projection of `UserId` is:

```
U1,U2
U2,U3
U3,U1
U4,U5
U4,U1
U5,U1
```

and similarly, the one mode projection of `ProjectID` is:

```
P1,P2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a `join` in SQL:

```
select t1.UserId, t2.UserId
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.ProjectId = t2.ProjectId;
```

Note:  If you have pairs that are connected through multiple projects and you do not want duplicates, then use `select distinct`.

Comment: I tried the join option, but for huge number of records it takes very very long time. Is this them most efficient way in sql?

Comment: Check my answer for WITH (NOLOCK) statement

Comment: @M.M . . . You want to be sure that the table has an index on `ProjectId` (and better yet `(ProjectId, UserId)`).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to make it run faster. By applying WITH (NOLOCK) statement, SQL is not utilizing any row level locks, responding faster.

```
select t1.UserId, t2.UserId
from t t1 WITH (NOLOCK) join
     t t2 WITH (NOLOCK)
     on t1.ProjectId = t2.ProjectId;
```

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff for the query